# svn log working hours of a particular month

Tags: svn

This is a task I'm doing each month as a freelancer for checking my hours in the invoice. I wonder, if there is a snippet for it.

```
-ranges in hours/minutes for each day
-List of such ranges for one month
```

The earliest commit of the day is the start, the latest is the end. Working only within usual working hours, no night work (thus, no begin on one day, end on the other)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't list hours, but at least days on which commit done and the last commit of the day:

```
#!/bin/bash
m=$1
y=$2
lastday=$(cal $(date +"$m %Y") | grep -v "^$" |tail -1|grep -o "..$")
svn log -r {$y-$m-01}:{$y-$m-$lastday} -q | grep 2016-06 | sort -r | uniq -f 7 | sort
```